# MongoDb query to calculate time between alternating on off switch

Tags: mongodb

```
{
metadata:{
eventcode:100
}
power:on // this can be either on or off
time:1667984669//unix timestamp
}
```

My document looks something like this the power can be on or it can be off, given to and from time I have to calculate how many hours it was on, I am having trouble because in 1 day it can even have 100 on and 100 off values which means 200 documents, so how to calculate the number of operational hour(i.e time that the system was on) in mongodb query?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone in the future faces the same problem:

```
       t.aggregate([
          {
            $match: {
              "metadata.eventCode": "100",
               actualtime:{$gte: 1662143400000,$lte:1662229799999}
            },
          },
          {
            $sort: { actualtime: 1 },
          },
          {
            $facet: {
              on: [
                {
                  $match: {
                    "metadata.type": "on",
                  },
                },
              ],
              off: [
                {
                  $match: {
                    "metadata.type": "off",
                  },
                },
              ],
            },
          },
        
        
          {
            $project: {
              operationalHours: {
                $sum: {
                  $map: {
                    input: {
                      $range: [
                        0,
                        {
                          $size: "$on",
                        },
                      ],
                    },
                    as:"el",
                    in: {
                      $subtract: [
                        {
                          $arrayElemAt: ["$off.actualtime", "$$el"],
                        },
                        {
                          $arrayElemAt: ["$on.actualtime", "$$el"],
                        },
                      ],
                    },
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          },
          
        ]);
```

Comment: This works only if you have a **strict** sequence of `on off on off on off`. The result will be wrong for example for `on off on off off off on off`. And what happens if you miss an "off", e.g. `on off on on off`?

Comment: You are correct here, I need to think about that also.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $set: { time: { $toDate: { $multiply: ["$time", 1000] } } } },
   {
      $setWindowFields: {
         partitionBy: "$metadata.eventcode",
         sortBy: { time: 1 },
         output: {
            off: {
               $last: "$time",
               window: { documents: ["current", 1] }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $match: { power: "on" } },
   {
      $set: {
         operationalHours: {
            $dateDiff: {
               startDate: "$time",
               endDate: "$off",
               unit: "hour"
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

You can customized it, let's assume you have glitch input data like this:

```
[
   { id: 1, power: 'on', time: 1667984669 },
   { id: 1, power: 'on', time: 1667984669 }, // accidentally inserted twice
   { id: 2, power: 'off', time: 1667984669 + 1000 },
   { id: 3, power: 'off', time: 1667984669 + 2000 },
   { id: 4, power: 'off', time: 1667984669 + 3000 }
]
```

then use

```
{
   $setWindowFields: {
      partitionBy: "$eventcode",
      sortBy: { time: 1 },
      output: {
         off: {
            $min: { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$power", "off"] }, "$time", null] },
            window: { documents: [1, "unbounded"] }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

it will take `time@id: 2 - time@id: 1`

Note, `$dateDiff` does not return fractional values. You may use `unit: "minute"` and divide result by 60.